# Removing all strings before first occurrence of a pattern in bash-script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

so i've got a problem.
I want to remove the whole content of a file before a certain pattern has been found, but only at the first occurrence of it.
the pattern : `([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).([0-9]{6})` (it is fits the date part of the string).

For example, this content:

```
-- 10:17:40.614568 00:00:00:00:00:00 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 303: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 289) 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:00:00:00:00:00, length 261, xid 0x1466f606, Flags [Broadcast]
```

should be parsed to :

```
10:17:40.614568 00:00:00:00:00:00 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 303: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 289) 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:00:00:00:00:00, length 261, xid 0x1466f606, Flags [Broadcast]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP mentioned condition to be met only for very first regex match in entire Input_file so adding this solution now.

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}/)  && !index{
  print substr($0,RSTART)
  index=1
  next
}
index ' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}/){
  print substr($0,RSTART)
}' Input_file
```

It will only print those lines which have a regex match found. In case you want to print those lines too which NOT have a match then do following.

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}/){
  print substr($0,RSTART)
  next
}
1' Input_file
```

Since I am using an OLD `awk` version so I have out `--re-interval` remove it in case for you above code works(new versions of `awk` it works)

***Explanation of 1st code:***

```
awk --re-interval '                                ##Starting awk program from here and --re-interval enables ERE for OLD versions of awk.
match($0,/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}/){  ##Using match utility of awk here which will check REGEX provided to it either it presents on line or not.
  print substr($0,RSTART)                          ##match utility/function has variable named RSTART which denotes the starting of REGEX point, so I am using substring function to print from starting of that point to till end of line, since OP want to remove everything before REGEX match.
}
' Input_file                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

For 2nd code's explanation will be same as 1st code only difference is 2nd code has `next` will skip lines whose regex is matched and `1` will print non-matched lines in Input_file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! but i need this awk command to work only once (for the first occurrence), and leave all the rest of the file to be as is. (actually cleaning the begging of the file only). Thanks!

Comment: @soosita, could you please check my EDIT solution now and let me know then? It will only check it once in entire Input_file.